# considerations on growing number of parameters in a neural network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I have built a convolutional neural network, in particular an AlexNet, and I have noticed that the number of parameters grow a lot as we go forward in the network. Now, I know that the parameters in the network is what we want to learn, and also know that its number grows as we go forward in the network because a summation wth other neurons is performed.

To me it seems like a crucial point to learn to unerstand truly how neural networks work, so my question is:

What are the implications of this growing number of parameters (if any)? And what considerations is it possible to do on this fact?

Thanks in advance.

[EDIT]For exampple, if I use an AlexNet, I have the following table:

[image]

which goes on until the last layer. The parameters in this table should be the weights.

Comment: What do you mean by `parameters`? Weights, biases? Or do you mean hyper-parameters i.e. kernel size, pool size?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You are right I was too wague. I meant the weights. I have edited my question with more details.

Comment: Generally, you need to fit right architecture's capacity to the problem. Too shallow net, may be inefficient to capture non-linear features in your data. Too deep may result in overfitting, in spite of low entropy. Basically, you have to compare different architectures. Without metrics, it's hard to tell anything _a priori_.

Comment: Thanks again for answering. In your opinion, can we say that the more we go from the start to the end, we are learning more because we have more parameters? I have no source for this, it is jut a reasoning I am doing. Thanks.